# Prometheus: extract a substring from a label value?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have similar services on the same host. For example I have two mysql server named mysql01 e mysql02. I have installed two `mysqld_exporter` one for each mysql server. The values of label instance are `instance="<host>-mysql01"` and `instance="<host>-mysql02"`. I have also installed `node_exporter` on the same host.

I wish to relate mysql_exporter series with node_exporter series.  For example, on the same grafana dashboard, dedicated to `mysql0x`, I wish to visualize metrics about swap memory and buffer pool size. So I need to visualize the following series:

```
mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size{instance="<host>-mysql0x"}
node_memory_SwapTotal_bytes{instance="<host>"}
```

How can I extract from instance label value `<host>-mysql0x` the `host` part?

As bonus question: there is a best practice to label similar service on the same host?

Answer (score 8):

you can use regex to do that as mentioned in the documentation.
http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/#filter-and-modify-the-options-using-a-regex-capture-group-to-return-part-of-the-text
[image]

Note: regex in image is  just example